# Как зашифровать закрытым ключом и расшифровать открытым?

Tags: python, rsa, криптография

Как собственно это сделать?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import rsa, binascii, sys

privatekey = 'bla'

pr = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(privatekey)


mess = rsa.encrypt('hello'.encode('utf8'), pr);


print(binascii.hexlify(mess))
```

Зашифровывается нормально. Но вот при расшифровке выдает ошибку

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import rsa, binascii, sys

publickey = 'bla'

pr = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(publickey)


mess = rsa.decrypt('hello'.encode('utf8'), pr);


print(binascii.hexlify(mess))
```

`AttributeError: 'PublicKey' object has no attribute 'blinded_decrypt'`

PS. если шифровать приватным ключом, то им можно и расшифровать.. получается некое симметричное шифрование.. это нормально?

Comment: Что за модуль `rsa`? Вроде нестандартный.

Comment: pip3 install rsa

Comment: В чем тогда смысл rsa если можно расшифровать окрытым ключем? Я так понимаю от вас хотят демонстрации собственной реализации RSA, в которой вы покажите почему расшифровать окрытым ключем трудная затея.

Comment: @AndrioSkur теоретически это можно использовать как подтверждение подлинности сообщения, того, что его создал именно владелец ключа. Хотя на практике для этого есть другие механизмы типа подписи)

Answer (score 1):

Ключи надо сгенерировать или загрузить, если они у вас уже сгенерированы

```
(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(512)
```

Потом можно будет использовать их для шифрования. Шифруют публичным.

```
crypto_mess = rsa.encrypt('hello'.encode('utf8'), pubkey);
```

И дешифрования. Дешифруют приватным.

```
mess = rsa.decrypt(crypto_mess, privkey)
```

Вот кусочек из самой библиотеки

```
def encrypt(message, pub_key):
    """Encrypts the given message using PKCS#1 v1.5
    :param message: the message to encrypt. Must be a byte string no longer than
        ``k-11`` bytes, where ``k`` is the number of bytes needed to encode
        the ``n`` component of the public key.
    :param pub_key: the :py:class:`rsa.PublicKey` to encrypt with.
    :raise OverflowError: when the message is too large to fit in the padded
        block.
```

Для шифрования необходимо использовать публичный ключ.

Comment: мне нужно наоборот: зашифровать закрытым ключом и расшифровать открытым

Comment: тогда вам нужна другая библиотека.

Comment: я добавил кусок кода из самой библиотеки из него видно, что для шифрования необходимо использовать публичный ключ